# Use variable instead of schema Eg dbo. for creating table

Tags: sql-server, variables

I would like to use variables instead of schema name in at create time for tables or views.

**Eg instead of**

```
create table dbo.TableName
```

**I want to**

```
create table @schema.TableName
```

Also I would like to write below statement with the mentioned solution.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.TableName', 'u') IS NOT NULL
    DROP table TableName;
go
```

Is this way totally possible or not, if it's possible which way is more efficient.

Comment: You cannot use variables or functions for things like schema, table or view name, column names etc. - these things have to be spelled out as literal text - unless you use dynamic SQL for everything (not recommended!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your statement concatenating objects names and use `sp_executesql` to submit it to the server:

[Using sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx)

For example, creating:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100);

SET @TableName = 'dbo.TableName';
SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' +  @TableName + ' ...';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

and dropping:

```
SET @TableName = 'dbo.TableName';
SET @SQLString = 'IF OBJECT_ID (''' + @TableName + ''', ''u'') IS NOT NULL DROP table ' + @TableName;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

You'll have to mitigate the "Sql Injection" risk if you are getting the object names from the user.

Comment: but what about this ?

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.TableName', 'u') IS NOT NULL
    DROP table TableName;
go

Comment: can you help me to use function inside the sp_executesql ? for example use EXECUTE sp_executesql dbo.myfunction(param1,param2);

Comment: @Arashbahreini: you cannot use functions directly in the `sp_executesql` call - you have to prepare the strings for the execution before actually calling `sp_executesql`

Comment: @Arashbahreini Have you tried `EXECUTE sp_executesql 'dbo.myfunction(param1,param2)'` (function call between single quotes)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to research "sqlcmd" mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx

Example.  Note, in SSMS, Under "Query" there is a "SqlCmd Mode" menu item you need to enable.

```
:setvar MySchemaName "dbo"


IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'$(MySchemaName)' and TABLE_NAME = N'Ticket' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [$(MySchemaName)].[Ticket] 
END 
GO


CREATE TABLE [$(MySchemaName)].[Ticket] ( 
    [TicketUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )

GO


SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'$(MySchemaName)' and TABLE_NAME = N'Ticket' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: I would go sqlcmd mode over string-concatenation.  sqlcmd.exe is a command line tool that allows variables to be passed into the procedure...via the command line.

Comment: I would advise not casually (not paying attention) to the phrase "Sql Injection Attach" from above.......SqlCmd isn't not that complicated.  Good luck.  Keep in mind that any design decisions you make early will cause you exponentially more time down the road.